# removing a string within nested array mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

```
const AllPostsSchema = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users'
    },
    posts: [{
        postid: {
            type: String
        },
        title: {
            type: String
        },
        category: {
            type: String
        },
        subcategory: {
            type: String
        }, category: {
            type: String
        },
        description: {
            type: String
        },
        name: {
            type: String
        },
        price: {
            type: Number
        },
        email: {
            type: String
        },
        phonenumber: {
            type: Number
        },
        language: {
            type: String
        },
        make: {
            type: String
        },
        model: {
            type: Number
        },
        odometer: {
            type: Number
        },
        condition: {
            type: String
        },
        state: {
            type: String
        },
        town: {
            type: String
        },
        city: {
            type: String
        },
        links: [{ type: String }],

        date: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        }
    }]

})    


 AllPosts.findOneAndUpdate({ 'user': req.query.userid },
                    { $pull: { 'posts': { 'links': req.query.link } } }
                )
                    .then(post => console.log(post))
```

i need to find a specific user and within that user match the post id  then remove one of the links in links array. when I do it like above it removes the whole array instead i want it to remove specific link within links array in posts arrayy.
Each user has one or more than one posts. I need to update a single post of a specific user. if a user wants to delete an image i delete that from amazon s3 then, i need to remove the link from that post link array so it doesnt create broken img tags in the front end.

```
AllPosts.findOneAndUpdate({ 'user': req.query.userid, 'posts.postid': req.query.postid },
                { $pull: { 'links': req.query.link } }
            )
                .then(post => console.log(post))
```

this also didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. For future reference :

```
  AllPosts.findOneAndUpdate({ 'user': req.query.userid, 'posts.postid': req.query.postid },
                    { $pull: { 'posts.$.links': req.query.link } }
                )
                    .then(post => console.log(post))
```